# NotImplementedError Python 2.7, sdl2 Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning Pygame/SDL2 and came across a error that is less than helpful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pygame.py", line 98, in <module>
  sys.exit(run())
File "pygame.py", line 94, in run
world.process()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sdl2/ext/ebs.py", line 238, in process
s_process(self, comps)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sdl2/ext/ebs.py", line 277, in process
raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

I understand that NotImplementedError is some specific type of Python error. My knowledge of Python is not at an expert level. Am I correct in believing that It simply means I have a typo or do I have a more systemic problem such as a version issue? Everything worked fine on previous steps in this tutoiral. I'm following this sdl2/pygame tutorial http://pysdl2.readthedocs.io/en/rel_0_9_4/tutorial/pong.html#adding-the-game-world

Here's my source code.

```
import sys
import sdl2
import sdl2.ext

WHITE = sdl2.ext.Color(255, 255, 255)

class SoftwareRenderer(sdl2.ext.SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem):
    def __init__(self, window):
        super(SoftwareRenderer, self).__init__(window)

    def render(self, components):
        sdl2.ext.fill(self.surface, sdl2.ext.Color(0, 0, 0))
        super(SoftwareRenderer, self).render(components)

class MovementSystem(sdl2.ext.Applicator):
    def __init__(self, minx, miny, maxx, maxy):
        super(MovementSystem, self).__init__()
        self.componenttypes = Velocity, sdl2.ext.Sprite
        self.minx = minx
        self.miny = miny
        self.maxx = maxx
        self.maxy = maxy

def process(self, world, componentsets):
    for velocity, sprite in componentsets:
        swidth, sheight = sprite.size
        sprite.x += velocity.vx
        sprite.y += velocity.vy

        sprite.x = max(self.minx, sprite.x)
        sprite.y = max(self.miny, sprite.y)

        pmaxx = sprite.x + swidth
        pmaxy = sprite.y + sheight
        if pmaxx > self.maxx:
            sprite.x = self.maxx - swidth
        if pmaxy > self.maxy:
            sprite.y = self.maxy - sheight

class Velocity(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Velocity, self).__init__()
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0

class Player(sdl2.ext.Entity):
    def __init__(self, world, sprite, posx=0, posy=0):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.sprite.position = posx, posy
        self.velocity = Velocity()

class Ball(sdl2.ext.Entity):
    def __init__(self, world, sprite, posx=0, posy=0):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.sprite.position = posx, posy
        self.velocity = Velocity()



def run():
    sdl2.ext.init()
    window = sdl2.ext.Window("The Pong Game", size=(800, 600))
    window.show()

    world = sdl2.ext.World()
    spriterenderer = SoftwareRenderer(window)
    world.add_system(spriterenderer)

    factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(sdl2.ext.SOFTWARE)
    sp_paddle1 = factory.from_color(WHITE, size=(20,100))
    sp_paddle2 = factory.from_color(WHITE, size=(20,100))

    sp_ball = factory.from_color(WHITE, size=(20, 20))

    movement = MovementSystem(0, 0, 800, 600)
    spriterenderer = SoftwareRenderer(window)

    world.add_system(movement)
    world.add_system(spriterenderer)

    ball = Ball(world, sp_ball, 390, 290)
    ball.velocity.vx = -3

    player1 = Player(world, sp_paddle1, 0, 250)
    player2 = Player(world, sp_paddle2, 780, 250)

    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        world.process()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

Thanks for any light you python Longhorns care to shed on this.

Comment: `NotImplementedError` means that they did created this function yet or they keep empty function and you have to create code in this function.

Comment: you have wrong indentions in code. `def process` has to be in `class MovementSystem`. Maybe it is function which is "not implemented" yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code you have wrong indentions with `def process(self, world, componentsets):`. It has to be class method.

Now it is function outside of class so `MovementSystem` use its default method `process()` (from `sdl2.ext.Applicator`) which has only one command `raise NotImplementedError()`. It is information for develores that they have to (over)write this function.

Comment: Dam you're right!. How did I miss that. I suppose python was unable to direct me to that specific line with an error because python has no way of knowing what I'm trying to create so the def process could have been completely legitimate to be separated. Thanks for your help.